# UICollectionViewCell is overlapped when scrolling

Tags: ios, user-interface

Following code is a very simple program which is used to display numbers from 1-10000 in the `UICollectionView`. It is displaying correctly without scrolling, but the cells are overlapped if you scroll down and scroll back the collection view.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10000;
}
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return CGSizeMake(100,30);
}
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *identifier = @"cell_id";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.item, nil]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the label is being added to the view's cell repeatedly. The old label is not removed when the cell is reused and hence you see multiple numbers overlapped. the solution can be to remove the old label like this

```
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

before adding to the cell. However this will create performance problems when the number of subviews increase. You can create a custom cell with a label and then update its value. I haven't tried it but i believe it will work. Hope this helps

Comment: Just curious. Is this the best way of doing it? What are the other options that are available?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in Swift 3:
Almost same solution as approved solution, note that I used

```
cell.subViews
```

instead of

```
cell.contentView.subViews
```

What's worked for me is:

```
for view in cell.subviews {
  view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Where did you use this? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I used inside the function

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell layer anchorPointZ to row index in cellForItemAtIndexPath: method

```
cell.layer.anchorPointZ = CGFloat(indexPath.row)
```