# UICollectionViewCell overlap disorder after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

This is my first application. I want to implement card stack like this.

[image]

I use `UICollectionView` for this app. And create overlap cell by `minimumLineSpacing =-20.f`

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0, 0, 0);
    collectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = -20.f;
```

and

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    CollectionNewCell *cell = (CollectionNewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius=10.0;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}
```

I found that after i scrolling, some cells overlap with others (for example : in yellow line)

[image]

I don't know what I'm wrong. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like this too. Did you happen to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I know, the question is very old, but answer is simple.

The problem here is that UICollectionView doesn't know how exactly you want arrange your cells in depth. So it just displays the last cell added to view hierarchy above other cells.

To fix this, you need to set proper cell zIndex. To do that, you need to use custom UICollectionViewLayout :)

Solution on Swift:

```
class MyCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        return super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)?.map { attributes in
            // Set cell's zIndex = cell's row, so each next cell will always overlap previous cell.
            attributes.zIndex = attributes.indexPath.row
            return attributes
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want create custom layout, there is another solution. Just override cell's method `apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes)` like this:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    ...

    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        layer.zPosition = CGFloat(layoutAttributes.indexPath.row)
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need remove all subview from cell

```
 for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
       if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
       }
 }
```

Comment: This looks like this answer from a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23648939/8653957. But it is not relevant to the OP's question because no labels are being added in `cellForRowAt:`.